# Minikube will not start again after a stop

Tags: kubernetes, linux, minikube

Running gentoo linux... I am new to kubernetes and learning it on my dev cloud. I am able to start minikube with no issues (other than the second node is missing...not sure why). Then I stop minikube. When I start it again it will not start with `GUEST_PROVISION_CONTAINER_EXITED`. I have to reboot my server to resolve it.

Anyone know how to fix this?

```
one@work ~
% minikube start --nodes=2


ð  minikube v1.22.0 on Gentoo 2.7 (amd64)
â¨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
ð  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
ð  Pulling base image ...
ð¤·  docker "minikube" container is missing, will recreate.
ð¥  Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=7300MB) ...
ð³  Preparing Kubernetes v1.21.2 on Docker 20.10.7 ...
    âª Generating certificates and keys ...
    âª Booting up control plane ...
    âª Configuring RBAC rules ...
ð  Verifying Kubernetes components...
    âª Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
ð  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass
â  The cluster minikube already exists which means the --nodes parameter will be ignored. Use "minikube node add" to add nodes to an existing cluster.
ð  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
one@work ~
% minikube status         
minikube         
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured

one@work ~
% minikube stop  
â  Stopping node "minikube"  ...
ð  Powering off "minikube" via SSH ...
ð  1 nodes stopped.
one@work ~
% minikube start --nodes=2
ð  minikube v1.22.0 on Gentoo 2.7 (amd64)
â¨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
ð  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
ð  Pulling base image ...
ð  Restarting existing docker container for "minikube" ...
ð¤¦  StartHost failed, but will try again: provision: get ssh host-port: unable to inspect a not running container to get SSH port
ð  Restarting existing docker container for "minikube" ...
ð¿  Failed to start docker container. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: provision: get ssh host-port: unable to inspect a not running container to get SSH port

â  Exiting due to GUEST_PROVISION_CONTAINER_EXITED: Docker container exited prematurely after it was created, consider investigating Docker's performance/health.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generic docker debugging help. I've installed minikube, but haven't ran into this particular inconvenience.

When it says "consider investigating Docker's performance/health" it probably means to check the docker logs

`docker ps --all`

should give you a list of images, if this is your only docker project, then it oughta be easier to find. The 3rd column in that list is the container_name parameter you want to feed to `docker logs [container_name]`

Whatever caused your container to stop prematurely ought to be in there.

Assuming you're running a production build of minikube, the chances are good it's something with your setup, probably filesystem related, but who can tell until you debug it.

Comment: Thanks.... the fix was to update docker....it was one version behind